# How to Append SMS Received to the ListView

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have the following code to display the message received in the listview:

```
package com.example.smsTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SMSReceiverActivity extends ListActivity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mIntentReceiver;
    ListView listview;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smsreceiver);

        listview=this.getListView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN");
        mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("get_msg");

            //Process the sms format and extract body &amp; phoneNumber
            msg = msg.replace("\n", "");
            String body = msg.substring(msg.lastIndexOf(":")+1, msg.length());
            String pNumber = msg.substring(0,msg.lastIndexOf(":"));

            //Add it to the list or do whatever you wish to
            ArrayList<String> bodyarr=new ArrayList<String>();
            bodyarr.add(body);
            arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SMSReceiverActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            bodyarr);           
            listview.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
            arrayAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver(mIntentReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.mIntentReceiver);
    }

}
```

However, the problem is the previous message is overwritten. I tried adding the `arrayAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();` code to no avail.

I also read a lot of answers here but it's not working on my code.

Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you receive a new message, you are creating a brand new, *empty* list, which is why the previous message is always overwritten.

Instead, move your declaration of bodyarr and arrayAdpt to class fields so that they can be shared and modified every time a new message is received:

```
private ArrayList<String> bodyarr = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt;
```

In onCreate, you should set the list adapter for your ListView:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_smsreceiver);

        listview = this.getListView();
        arrayAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SMSReceiverActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        bodyarr);

        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdpt);
    }
```

Then, in your onReceive method for your broadcast receiver, you can do almost exactly what you were doing before, except using the already existing list and array adapter, so that what you've already added will not be overwritten:

```
mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("get_msg");

        //Process the sms format and extract body &amp; phoneNumber
        msg = msg.replace("\n", "");
        String body = msg.substring(msg.lastIndexOf(":")+1, msg.length());
        String pNumber = msg.substring(0,msg.lastIndexOf(":"));

        bodyarr.add(body);

        arrayAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```